# How to create a Objective C class for Buffer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, nsdata

I am getting buffer with its length in a function

> - (void)putEncodedData:(void *)data ofSize:(unsigned)size

I want to create a custom class for this buffer data  with name AudioData with variables data,size . How to set its @property attribues ?  Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't bother. You can encode a collection of bytes with its size in an `NSData` already; use that.